# Angular - Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8, angular2-ngmodel, angular2-databinding

I have an `Angular 8` app.

**app.component.html**

```
 <div>
    <label class="form-check-label f-14">
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="isAgree" [(ngModel)]="isAgree" #isAgree="ngModel"/> Agree?
    </label>
 </div>
```

But this is throwing the error.

> compiler.js:7627 Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!
>       at _AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (compiler.js:7627)

I want to understand this error definition & cause. **How can I get rid of this**?

Also, I don't want to declare any variable in my `app.component.ts`. I need to access the `isAgree` flag value in view. So ideally I was trying as below.

```
<div>
    <label class="form-check-label f-14">
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="isAgree"  #isAgree/> Agree?
    </label>
    <p> {{isAgree}} </p> 
 </div>
```

But the value is not reflecting.

**How can I get the value in this way?**

I know I am combining 2 questions but both seem very relevant. Hence did so.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you named `[(ngModel)]` and reference variable the same (`isAgree`). Try renaming one or another...

Answer (score 2):

```
 <div>
    <label class="form-check-label f-14">
       <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"  [(ngModel)]="isAgree" #isAgree.value="ngModel"/> Agree?
    </label>
 </div>
<div>
```

Above code will work fine.

`#isAgree` refers to the input element. you have to bind to its value property 
`#isAgree.value="ngModel`

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're getting is because you're trying to assign a variable `isAgree` in the template which has already been defined in the component.

The following is all you need as long as you have the property `isAgree` in your component. The two way binding using `[(ngModel)]` will ensure this property is updated whenever the input value changes (and vice versa):

```
<div>
  <label class="form-check-label f-14">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="isAgree" [(ngModel)]="isAgree"/>
    Agree?
  </label>
  <p>{{isAgree}}</p> 
</div>
```